# AVFoundation and UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, avfoundation

Faced a problem. I want to make an app that consists of two tables. There are a label and a view in the first table, and a button and a view in the second table. And I want to play the same video file from the Internet in all labels from both tables. But something goes wrong ... Where are my mistakes? Maybe someone can help me.

I gave the tables different tags. And made for each of the tables custom cell.

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstTable: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var secondTable: UITableView!
let firstCell = "firstCell"
let secondCell = "secondCell"
let avPlayer = AVPlayer()
var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    firstTable.delegate = self
    firstTable.dataSource = self
    
    secondTable.delegate = self
    secondTable.dataSource = self
    
    avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
    view.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)
    
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v")
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url! as URL)
    avPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.viewWillAppear(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: avPlayer.currentItem)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let seconds : Int64 = 0
    let preferredTimeScale : Int32 = 1
    let seekTime : CMTime = CMTimeMake(seconds, preferredTimeScale)
    avPlayer.seek(to: seekTime)
    avPlayer.isMuted = true
    avPlayer.play()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (tableView.tag == 1) {
        return 30
    } else if (tableView.tag == 2) {
        return 20
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    if (tableView.tag == 1) {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: firstCell, for: indexPath) as! FirstTableViewCell
        cell.numCell.text = String(indexPath.row)
        viewVideo(viewer: cell.videoCell)
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: secondCell, for: indexPath) as! SecondTableViewCell
        cell.buttonCell.setTitle(String(indexPath.row), for: .normal)
        cell.buttonCell.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.buttonCell.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showAlertForRow(sender :)), for: .touchUpInside)
        viewVideo(viewer: cell.videoSecondCell)
        return cell
    }
    
}

func viewVideo(viewer: UIView) {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    viewer.layer.addSublayer(avPlayerLayer)
    avPlayerLayer.frame.size = CGSize(width: viewer.frame.width, height: viewer.frame.height)
}

@IBAction func showAlertForRow(sender: UIButton) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title:"Test work",message:"Cell at row \(sender.tag) was tapped!",preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This is a gif with my problem?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wind answer. AvPlayerLayer should be inside cell. But like me, there was one player for all the cells.